# Is it possible to do an upgrade without having to answer questions?

Tags: upgrade

I did a `update-manager -d` and since it is asking if i should replace or leave several files like for example the mysql conf file. Do I have an option to tell it to upgrade everything no questions asked. Something like a silent install or to have everything automatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following might help you :

edit/create /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/force-confnew

```
sudo vim /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/force-confnew
```

and add the following :

```
force-confnew
```

It'll say to dpkg to always put the package maintainer version of the file.

Delete the file when your upgrade is finished.

update-manager will still ask you the basic questions but it'll not ask you about if you agree to change this or that file.

Dpkg may still have questions but it is better for you to not disable it. If you still want dpkg to be quiet replace force-confnew by force-all

WARNING 1 : This is a dangerous option. It'll delete any modifications you made on the files that are changed. And with this option you'll not be aware witch file is changed.

WARNING 2 : As 12.04 is still in development the packages that are installed can have bugs. This include trouble in the installation/upgrade process. It may break your system.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Apt-get allows the -y option to automatically answer "yes" to questions such as those. I believe the correct command would be

```
# apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```